# Why char array displays an additional text in the array elements?

Tags: c#, arrays

why do we get the `extra text` within the `char array` in c#, looks like a *char equivalent* but just wondering are there any advantages of having this within the char array, if so where do we use this feature.

[image]

Comment: What extra text? What you see is the value each element in the array next to its string representation

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Extra Text: The numbers within the red marked rectangle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the integer representation of the char within the ASCII table

Answer (score 1):

They're the ASCII values of what numerical value the characters represent.

http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is purely the watch window that is showing you the `char byte` value and the actual `char string` vaule.

So, from [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) you can see that `48 is '0'` and `49 is '1'`

Comment: It is not the ASCII value (that just happens to match for the first 127 characters), but the unicode character code (code point)

Answer (score 0):

Characters in C# are Unicode, and there are plenty of them. And there are plenty of them that look similar or downright identical or even unreadable. In such cases you need these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As per the C# Reference, each char from char array shows the Decimal value of it